# python module firewall not found

Tags: ansible

- computer run ansible-playbook: MacBook, with python 3.9
- target machine: Debian 10 with python2.7.16 and python3.7.3

When I tried to open port in firewall:

```
- name: Open port 80 for http access
firewalld:
  service: http
  permanent: true
  state: enabled
```

I got error:

> fatal: [virtual_server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Python
> Module not found: firewalld and its python module are required for
> this module,                         version 0.2.11 or newer required
> (0.3.9 or newer for offline operations)"}

I also tried to use ansible.posix.firewall, with `ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix` on macbook, and use ansible.posix.firewall, still got this error.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`ansible.posix.firewalld` depends on the python firewalld bindings which are missing for the python version ansible is running under.

See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2091931 for a similar problem on systems using the EPEL8 ansible package, where the python3-firewall package is built against python 3.6 but ansible is using python 3.8.

`ansible --version` or `head -1 $(which ansible)` will tell you what version of Python ansible uses.

On redhat systems, `dnf repoquery -l python3-firewall` will tell you what version of Python python3-firewall is built against.

The solution is to install the appropriate python-firewalld package for your OS that matches the version of python ansible is using, if one exists.

If a compatible python-firewalld package does not exist, you can configure ansible to use a different version of python by setting the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable or the `interpreter_python` ansible.cfg setting (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html).

Answer (score 3):

if you have your playbook vars like this

```
---
- hosts: testbench
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

then your firewall task should be like this

```
- name: open ports
  ansible.posix.firewalld:
      permanent: true
        immediate: true
        port: "{{item}}/tcp"
        state: enabled
      become: true
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
      with_items:
        - tcp-port-1
        - tcp-port-2
        - tcp-port-3
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you propably have awx installed on docker and he dont have that galaxy package do this :

**1. go to main server**

```
 > docker images
```

find smt like this

```
ansible/awx    17.1.0    {here_id_of_image}   16 months ago    1.41GB
```

**2. connect to that docker image**

```
> docker run -it {here_id_of_image} bash
```

**3. Run command to install pkg**

```
> ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
```

Done now run your playbook

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by switch `ansible_connection` mode from `paramiko` to `ssh` on Ansible 5.10.0 x Ubuntu 22.04 .

My changes.

```
  [ chusiang@ubuntu-22.04 ~ ]
  $ vim ansible-pipeline.cfg
  [defaults]
- ansible_connection = paramiko
- transport = paramiko
+ ansible_connection = ssh
+ transport = ssh
```

Ansible version.

```bash
[ chusiang@ubuntu-22.04 ~ ]
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.10]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/chusiang/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/chusiang/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/chusiang/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/chusiang/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, Nov  2 2022, 18:53:38) [GCC 11.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True
```

Pip versions of ansible.

```
[ chusiang@ubuntu-22.04 ~ ]
$ pip list | grep -i ansible
ansible                         5.10.0
ansible-core                    2.12.10
ansible-inventory-to-ssh-config 1.0.1
ansible-lint                    3.5.1
```

Enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Debian 10, but it may be similar to the issue I had on Ubuntu 22.04 where I received the same error when trying to use the Ansible firewalld module to add a service.

The reason was that the host was running the UFW firewall and did not have firewalld installed.

The solution was to stop and disable UFW on the target host, and then install, enable and start firewalld in its place. The Ansible firewalld module then worked fine.

I used this playbook:

```
- name: firewall | disable and stop ufw
  service:
    name: ufw
    enabled: false
    state: stopped


- name: firewall | install required packages for firewalld
  package:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
  with_items:
    - firewalld


- name: firewall | enable and start firewalld
  service:
    name: firewalld
    enabled: true
    state: started


- name: firewalld | allow incoming HTTP connections
  firewalld:
    service: http
    permanent: true
    immediate: yes
    state: enabled
  notify: reload_firewalld
```

with handler

```
- name: reload_firewalld
  systemd:
    name: firewalld
    state: reloaded
```