# Failed to open port using ansible

Tags: python, ansible, port, firewall, influxdb

Created a script for installing Influxdb and I tried to open the port using Ansible and got an error

```yaml
- name:  permit traffic in default zone on port 8086/tcp
  firewalld:
      port: 8086/tcp
      permanent: yes
      state: enabled
```

> fatal: [jumphost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Python Module not found: firewalld and its python module are required for this module, version 0.2.11 or newer required (0.3.9 or newer for offline operations)"}

Comment: Use `python3 -m pip install firewall` or `python -m pip install firewall` according to your need in terminal.

Comment: It might be a good idea to start your playbook with a `pip` section that installs the modules needed.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [documentation for the module firewalld](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html), the module requires

- firewalld >= 0.2.11
- python-firewall >= 0.2.11

So these requirements must be present on the target system, in your case "jumphost". You did not state what kind of OS you are working on, so I will just assume a Red Hat flavor.

1. Ensure firewalld is installed and running. On Linux using systemd, you can verify this using `systemctl status firewalld`. The service should be marked as "active (running)". If it is not installed, you need to install it. On Red Hat flavors, this can be done with `yum install firewalld`. After that ensure it is started using `systemctl start firewalld`.
2. Ensure the Python module firewall is installed for the Python interpreter you are using with Ansible. If you use Python 3 and only have one Python interpreter installed, `python3 --version` should give you the version. Without knowing you system flavor, I can't know how you should install the Python module, but for Red Hat flavors of Linux, it can be installed with `yum install python3-firewall`. This will install the module for your system Python interpreter, so it is important that you use that interpreter when running Ansible.

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448139/7400759